# What Angular files are safe to delete when sharing a project?

Tags: angular

I would like to share an Angular project, it is mostly the basic application created by

```
ng new my-app
```

but it is 340MB (100MB zipped).  Are there any temporary folders etc that can be safely deleted in Angular?

I tried googling this but cannot find anything related.

Comment: Is sharing it through e.g. GitHub an option?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery could do but it's only of temporary usefulness.  Excluding the folders in the answer cut it down to under 1MB :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they will be building and running npm i then you can drop these folders

dist

dist-dev

node_modules

That should eliminate the bulk of the mg.